# Can I append new section in wizard using JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html

Can I append a new section in wizard when press on button?

With the code below, it appends inside body of section only.

```
<button class="btn btn-light bd btn-block mg-l-10 wd-70 ht-40" type="button" value="Add" id="add" onclick="myappendfun(); " title="Add">Add</button>
<div id="wizard1">
  <div id="parentarvhandling"></div>
</div>
```

```
function myappendfun() { 
  $('#wizard1').steps({
  headerTag: 'h3',
  bodyTag: 'section',
  transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
  autoFocus: true,
  titleTemplate: '#index# #title#'
});
$('#parentarvhandling').append('<h3>Personal Information</h3><section><p>hello</p></section>');
}
```

Comment: why you don't use append for wizard also?

Comment: what's the error in the console. Is it per chanse "undefined steps function"?

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai Probably `$.(...).steps is not a function`

Comment: no error  in my console

Comment: so, can i append section in wizard or not by press button add section

Comment: @jack You can try something like `actionContainerTag: "div class='modal-footer actions'",` and remove `modal-footer` from you html and set `p-0` class into `modal-body`.